# Vue Component: Dropdown menu open inside div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I’m building a dropdown component for my project. But when i add the component is a responsive table the menu is open within the div.

Here is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-pond-pto57t?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue

[image]

How can i make the dropdown-menu to append to the body and set a transform(x,y)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `position: fixed !important;`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
    };
  },
})
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="demo">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Joe Band</td>
          <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropdown-toggle" @click="showMenu = !showMenu">
                Action
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" :class="{ show: showMenu }">
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply `position-fixed` class to `.dropdown-menu` instead of `!important`.

Comment: Btw, proper solution is to use Popper. This is precisely why Bootstrap uses Popper: `position: fixed` only works if no ancestor is 3d transformed: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-monad-f9sbkp?file=/src/App.vue. If it's 3d transformed it becomes viewport and `fixed` becomes relative to that element, not to `<body>`. Behind the scenes, Popper appends the popper content to whatever element is set as boundary.

Comment: Great idea to use `position: fixed`, Nikola. I've taken it a step further and also attached the menu to `<body>`, to fix the issue I was talking about. Cheers!

Comment: Will do some reading on popper and also the `position: fixed`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I find both existing answers valuable, but neither complete:

- [TripleN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73957944/1891677) doesn't position the dropdown correctly
- [Nikola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73960675/1891677) doesn't append `.dropdown-menu` to `<body>`, so it stops working as soon as one of the ancestors of `.dropdown` has any valid `transform` value other than `none` ([spec ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#containing-block-for-all-descendants)). Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-monad-f9sbkp?file=/src/App.vue).

In my estimation, the correct solution would be to do both:

1. allow Popper (used internally by Bootstrap 5) to position the dropdown (the popper content) correctly,
2. append the popper content to `<body>` while dropdown is open.

That's pretty much it!
This particular task used to be easy in prior versions of Bootstrap.
I've spent hours going through Bootstrap 5's and Popper's documentation and examples, trying to find a way to do this simple task: specify a target `container` for popper content.

If someone knows how to achieve this in Bootstrap 5 *without* having to meddle with DOM ourselves, I'd be delighted to learn how.
Eventually I gave up and ended up moving the menu in DOM myself, after Popper positions it:

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hoover-mzo5b1?file=/src/App.vue).
In more detail, this hybrid solution:

- uses Nikola's idea to give the menu `position: fixed`, so Popper does the heavy lifting of positioning
- uses TripleN's idea to append the menu to `<body>`, after Popper positioned it. Additionally, I'm moving the menu back to its original place in DOM once the dropdown is closed. It might not be necessary, but to me it makes a lot of sense. Common sense.

The solution seems to work in all cases, including inside 3d transformed ancestors. I've smoke tested it in both latest Vue 2 (`2.7.10`) and latest Vue 3 (`3.2.40`). Does the job.

Same exact logic in [Composition](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-darkness-futp2o?file=/src/components/Dropdown.vue).

---

Side note: perhaps I'm too demanding but, by comparison with prior versions, I find Bootstrap 5 difficult to work with and poorly documented, at least at this point in time.

This should have been a trivial task. Specify `container: 'body'` in Dropdown's config. Done!

I'm a bit disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

Split dropdown menu into other component, in `mounted` hook use `document.body.appendChild` drowdown menu elemement (`this.$el`).
I have already updated in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-grass-63dw85).

Hope this help!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe when you modify someone else's codesandbox, the sandbox is automatically forked. So the one you modified most likely has a different url than OP's.

Comment: I have modified but sandbox don't generate new url

Comment: When I open link in question I don't see any of the changes you talk about. Open the question link in incognito window. Do you see your changes?

Comment: thank u, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-grass-63dw85) is my forked sandbox

Comment: Very good idea, in principle, but you might agree placing the dropdown menu under the table is not ideal. Especially if the table is long :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and help. Will check out the `this.$el` and maybe try reading on the best UI experience instead of dropdown in table

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for vue 3's teleport component. By specifying a target element, you can tell Vue to send that element to the target element.

For example:

```
<Teleport to='body'>... this content will be sent to the body</Teleport>
```

The `to` property can be any valid selector or even a `ref` to another element.

You can also use the `disabled` property to programmatically disable the teleport. In this case the content of the component will remain where it was original placed.

If you're not using VUE 3, you can still very easily bang out a component that will mimic this same behavior. The teleport is great for things like modals, because it allows you to break free from the positioning constraints imposed by having a nested element.

For more information, check out the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html) for the teleport component.